# indexOf returns -1 searchInCollection

Tags: java, list

I'm so very sorry if this has been asked before. I'm new to this. Im ready for downvotes, just please help :/

My Code:

```
public void searchInCollection() {
        query = "ASD123";
        int indexOfQuery = carData.indexOf(query);
        System.out.println(indexOfQuery);
        carData.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Output is:

run:

```
-1
Bil: Ford ASD123
Årsmodell: 1900
Ägare: Asd Asd 
Mätarställning: 1937
Inlämnad: Thu Jan 02
Beräknad tid att laga: 10 arbetsdagar
Beräknad kostnad för lagning: 6613 kronor
Bil: Volvo QWE123
Årsmodell: 1950
Ägare: David Ahlstrlm 
Mätarställning: 26839
Inlämnad: Thu Jan 02
Beräknad tid att laga: 13 arbetsdagar
Beräknad kostnad för lagning: 10435 kronor
Bil: Motorolo ZXC123
Årsmodell: 2000
Ägare: Zxc Zxc 
Mätarställning: 37706
Inlämnad: Thu Jan 02
Beräknad tid att laga: 19 arbetsdagar
Beräknad kostnad för lagning: 9931 kronor
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

As you can see the list is there with the data and the searchquery should return line 1. But it doesn't.  I'm losing my mind here...

To clarify: I want to search for the element (string) "ASD123" in the list and find the indexposition.

Comment: What type is `carData`?

Comment: The first item of the list is "Bil: Ford ASD123", not "ASD123". Index -1 means that your item is not on the list. EDIT: I mean "ASD123" doesnt exist on your list

Comment: public List<String> carData = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you change your query to "Bil: Ford ASD123", the index will not be -1

Comment: That is correct! How do i search for the element (string) "ASD123" in the list and find the indexposition? the query must be in a license plate format so...

Comment: Just iterate through the list and check if current item contains your query, if so, call list.indexOf(currentItem); That will return the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `carData` was a string, then you would get the index. However, it is a list of string, so when you say `carData.indexOf("ASD123")`, you are searching for a string in the list which equates to `ASD123` exactly, not a string in the list which contains the search string.

One way to get the index could be to iterate over the list and then do `indexOf` on each item in the list:

```
int index = 0;
boolean resultFound = false;
for (String car : carData) {
    if (car.indexOf(query) != -1) {
        resultFound = true;
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
if (resultFound) {
    ...
}
```

You need the `resultFound` flag because you want to make sure you didn't loop over the whole list without finding a match.

Answer (score 1):

since `carData` is list of string , then the method `indexOf` will return the index if the full string match not part of it.

I suggest you define your own find method

```
private int findFirstContain(String str , List<String> list){
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(list.get(i).contains(str)) return i;
    }
    return -1
}
```

and then use it in `searchInCollection` method

```
public void searchInCollection() {
        query = "ASD123";
        int indexOfQuery = findFirstContain(query , carData);
        System.out.println(indexOfQuery);
        carData.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` will not find the query you give because your first element is `Bil: Ford ASD123` and not `ASD123`. They should be an exact match. You can try to loop through the list and see if any String element in it contains 'ASD123' in it

```
int index = 0;
    for(String str: carData) {
        if(str.contains(query)) { break; }
           index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list doesn't contains an item that is equals to your String "ASD123"
the first Item in your List is "Bil: Ford ASD123", and `"Bil: Ford ASD123".equals("ASD123")` returns `false`

`indexOf` methode is comparing using `equals` methode

```
 /**
   * Returns the lowest index at which element appears in this List, or
   * -1 if it does not appear.
   *
   * @param e the element whose inclusion in the List is being tested
   * @return the index where e was found
   */
   public int indexOf(Object e)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       if (equals(e, data[i]))
         return i;
     return -1;
 }
```

[Source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html)